# Heroku not returning a Django JsonResponse

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have an django app which is being hosted by Heroku. My problem is that the Heroku is not returning the Json response. I know the code is working because the Heroku logs are printing the data, and response, in the log window yet Heroku is returning a 500 error. Below is what is being printed in the log console.

```
Jul 31 09:26:20 app heroku/router at=info method=POST path="/path2post/" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=81b525af-adc7-4c18-b5c6-477396541681 fwd="x.x.x.x" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12500ms status=500 bytes=210 protocol=https
Jul 31 08:03:27 app app/web.1 RUNTIME of get_advertiser_organic_pins: 10.77 seconds. 
Jul 31 08:03:27 app app/web.1 <JsonResponse status_code=200, "application/json">
Jul 31 08:03:27 app app/web.1 x.x.x.x - - [31/Jul/2020:15:03:26 +0000] "POST /organic/ HTTP/1.1" 500 27 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.26.2"
```

here is the code in my views.py

```
# POST organic/
def get_data(request):
    if request.method in ["POST", "OPTIONS"]:
        access_token = request.headers.get("token")
        if access_token is None:
            return JsonResponse(
                {
                    "error": "Access token is missing",
                }
            )
        request.session["access_token"] = access_token
        request_payload = json.loads(request.body)

        profile_id = request_payload["selectedProfile"]["externalId"]
        try:
            profiles_data = get_air_data(request, profile_id, view_caller=True)
            data = atmospheric_digest(profiles_data)
        except Exception as error:
            return JsonResponse(
                {
                    #"error": f"{error}",
                    "error": str(data),
                },
                status=401,
            )
        payload = {
            "data": data,
        }
    print(JsonResponse(payload))
    return JsonResponse(payload)
```

Comment: Try to make the error in your question reproducible. We don't know what `get_air_data` or `atmospheric_digest` are. If you hardcode the payload, do you still get the problem? Did you try running `manage.py runserver` locally? That might narrow down whether Heroku is the issue. Perhaps the repeated `JsonResponse(payload)` twice is the problem. I would suggest doing `response = JsonResponse(payload); print(response); return response`.

Comment: As an aside, `"error": str(data),` won't work because `data` hasn't been defined. Perhaps you mean `"error": str(error)`? I would be wary of returning exceptions in the HTTP response, you might leak sensitive information.